# Can I use blind rivets in concrete?

Tags: concrete, rivets

Somebody told me about using blind rivets (5mm) to attach drywall steel tracks on concrete floor and ceiling. Do that really works?

How good is this compared with bushing and screw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing with using a rivet would be the precision of the drilled hole. Given the right size hole, it would absolutely be strong, (maybe not AS strong) but that hole would need to be drilled to a roundness within about +0.05" of the diameter of the rivet, which I highly doubt you'd be able to accomplish with a hand drill in concrete. Too loose and the rivet doesn't grab. Too tight, the rivet can't even try to grab and will break off before the pin moves.

Screws that are developed to hold in concrete will obviously be better because there's a lot more surface area to grab onto the concrete, and they're more friendly on inconsistent holes due to the depth of the threads.

Answer (score 1):

I would not count on something like that for a real connection. Something like a tapcon would be a much better choice.

Comment: I was suspicious of that too. Unfortunately tapcon is inexistent in Brazil, therefore I must use bushing-screw or a hilti gun (which is very expensive)...